# UITabBar Icons not appearing correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm working on a iOS app. I have a tabbar with 5 View Controllers. All the icons are set in the Storyboard:

[image]

When I launch the app, 2 are messed up. The Home (first TabBar View Controller) is practically missing and the last one (Messages) is not even looking the way it should be. I have no clue what's happening. The home tab bar icon is completely gone and the messages unselected icon is not looking the same.

I can guarantee you that all icons are in the Assets folder. 
[image]

But when I launch the app it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE: I Figured out the Message Tabbar Item (Render as: original image solved that). That's fixed. But the home item is still not showing.**

Comment: Share your sample project. (With tabbar and icon images). Try this: Remove storyboard references and attach tab item connection with navigation controller directly. And then add storyboard reference for View controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around for hours, I finally figured it out. Basically, since I've changed the order in that `UIStoryboard`, the `TabBarItem` in the `UINagivationController` of the Home View Controller was deleted. All you have to do is to add a new `TabBarItem` in the `UINagivationController` and set the image/icon you'd like.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this One

**Go to Assets folder. Select your tab image. On the right side under Attributes you will find "Render As". Select "Original Image".**

Comment: Thank you but that was already suggested and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your view controller and select tabbar (tap on bottom icon)

and set selected image and image

[image]

After that goto your Image Assets and change the rendering  mode  to original for selected image

[image]

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Double checked this and it's the same with my project as well. It's not that.

Comment: @Dani Are you doing anything programatically ?

Comment: The only thing I have is to setup the `tabBar.tintColor`, `tabBar.barTintColor` and the `tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor`. That's it. It was all working BEFORE I've added a Container view and embedded that View Controller into the container view.

Comment: @Dani Could you please comment that stuff for just testing and check weather it is working of nor

Answer (score 1):

make sure all image is in your project asset folder.

[image: Please see attach]

Comment: That's why I've posted some screenshots to show that All images are indeed there. I knew people would suggest that. But they are in the assets folder.

Comment: @Dani may you please you share your project?

Answer (score 0):

make sure downloaded icons are of the size 25*25 for the 1x size. That would work.

Comment: Nope. Sadly it didn't work. None of the icon is that size by the way. They all work. Home also worked till recently and then it disappeared. Before that it worked and I haven't touched the assets folder.